# Query condition with entity referenced via custom field

Tags: entities

We have the usual way to reference related tables through JOINs using:

```
$query->condition('foo.entity:type.bar', $value);
```

But how can this be specified when `foo` is not a direct field but a complex custom one with more than one columns? Say `complex_field` has three columns, `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`. In a simple condition, without a join, this works (yes, I could also specify the main property that is used as a default when nothing is specified, this is not important here):

```
$query->condition('complex_field.foo1', $value);
```

However, trying to use this field as the reference to another entity fails:

```
$query->condition('complex_field.foo1.entity:type.bar', $value);
```

results in *Invalid specifier: 'entity'.*

For reference, let's consider this field:

```
public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition): array {
  return [
    'columns' => [
      'foo1' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => FALSE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'foo2' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => FALSE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'foo3' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => FALSE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
    ],
    'indexes' => [
      'foo1' => ['foo1'],
      'foo2' => ['foo2'],
      'foo3' => ['foo3'],
    ],
    'foreign keys' => [
      'foo1' => [
        'table' => 'table_foo1',
        'columns' => ['foo1' => 'foo1_id'],
      ],
      'foo2' => [
        'table' => 'table_foo2',
        'columns' => ['foo2' => 'foo2_id'],
      ],
      'foo3' => [
        'table' => 'table_foo3',
        'columns' => ['foo3' => 'foo3_id'],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: The core entity reference field type has two properties, `target_id` and `entity`. What is `foo1` in your second example?

Comment: An integer that serves as a foreign key. Basically the same as `target_id` there. I'll add the schema to the question.

Comment: By the way, yes, the online discussions mention just this case, `file.target_id.entity`. Mostly identical to my case, that's why I wonder why it doesn't work for me. People discuss that `file.entity` should also work because `target_id` is the main property but, as I mentioned in the question, I'm perfectly happy with specifying the column manually, especially as I have three, and only one could be default, anyway.

Comment: You can't directly join arbitrary tables or fields in a condition. The join though the `.entity` notation is tied to entity reference fields, this magic will not work with other field types.

Comment: OK, I see. Considering that I already have live data, the simplest approach will be a `hook_query_TAG_alter()` for these cases, I can do whatever JOIN I want then. This isn't a contrib module but an internal need for a single site. I also considered replicating the funcionality of the entity reference but with everything said thrice, it wasn't that attractive a solution... Actually, all other requirements are well served with the field as is, so there's really no need to rework the whole for just this single query.